# Have my discord bot respond when two different words are said in one message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

This is a really simple question, but I'm making an incredibly simple bot (small, private friend server) and I can't figure out how to do this, nor have I been able to look up anything that matches what I'm looking for.

How do I make it so that my bot will only respond if two different words are sent in one message?

Here's an example:

```
 if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('egg')) {
  message.channel.send(egg(message));
 } else
```

With the function of "egg(message)" declared elsewhere in the code, of course. My bot will respond to anyone who sends a message with the word "egg" anywhere in it with a randomly generated response, which works fine.

What I want to know is if it's possible to, say, have the bot respond if anyone says the words "egg" and "bacon" in one message. Meaning, I want it to respond if **both** of those two words are said anywhere in a message, but to **not** respond if **only** "egg" or "bacon" is said. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&&`, which stands for **and** in conditions, like so:

```
let msg_content = message.content.toLowerCase()
if (msg_content.includes('egg') && msg_content.includes('bacon')) {
  message.channel.send(egg(message));
 }
```